# How to use libraries created in Xcode for another Xcode project?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I created a C++ library in Xcode and I simply want to use it in another project. However, even after linking the dynamic library file from the build of the other file under "Link Binary with Libraries," I still get this error: library not found for -l(name).

Following some other suggestions from similar questions, I added another library search path directly to the library. It seems that Xcode is only trying to link from the following path:`Users/(myname)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sheetmusictest-gscrqsklkiocvngyivsszqxfrrse/Build/Products/Debug/Sheetmusictest`

This doesn't seem right anyways due to how hidden the path is. Is there a way to correctly get a library from a previous Xcode project and use it in a new one?

Comment: Is "Sheetmusictest" the new project or the old (library) one?

Comment: @JaMiT it is the console app I am trying to link the library to.

Comment: OK, the path you mentioned is probably the "current" directory when the compile takes place, and it is normal for the current directory to be searched for libraries. Often you do not want to make use of that, though. Moving on to something else: how did you add another library search path, and what path did you add? And just to check: where is the dynamic library you created?

Comment: @JaMiT I clicked on the project in the left pane, went to build settings, scrolled down to search paths, and added under "Library Search Paths" in "Debug" and "Release" I added this `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Sheetmusictest/Libraries`     Also, here is the full path to the Library folder `/Users/myname/Desktop/Personal Workspace/Sheetmusictest/Sheetmusictest/Libraries`

Comment: You missed the last question: where is the dynamic library you created?

Comment: @JaMit Initially it was in a directory similar to the one in my original question, then I copied it into the "Libraries" folder. Something interesting to note is when I put the dynamic library into the directory in the original question and build, this error shows up: /usr/local/lib/libSheetmusic.dylib: code signature in (/usr/local/lib/libSheetmusic.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?). It makes me think I'm not exporting/copying the library the way it wants?

Comment: You may want to update your question with some of this information. Specifically: the path you added to "Library Search Paths", the file(s) you copied to that path, and the clarification that "Sheetmusictest" is the new project. It might be useful to mention what happens when you link against the original location, but I suspect that error is a different question.